# Multiple nextjs params with supabase for dynamic routing

Tags: next.js, supabase

I have started a small project (to learn Nextjs) with supabase and have hit a small roadblock. The basic overview is I have a table for stores (name, email, address, slug) and a table for socials (FK store => stores.id, name, url) which is linked via a foreign key on store => stores.id. Each store should have a separate page in the app where I will display their information and their social accounts.

I started by creating a dynamic route [id].tsx with:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
    const { data: store, error } = await supabase
        .from('stores')
        .select('*, socials(*)')
        .eq('id', params.id)
        .single();

    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    
    }

  return {
    props: {
        store
    },
  }
}
```

The above works just fine in my **export default function Store ({store})** and I can see the stores information by going to localhost:3000/1 (only store set up currently). This does lead to my roadblock unfortunately. I would like the '1' to be the actual store slug (column in the stores table) like localhost:3000/lorem-ipsum but keep the relation between the two tables on the store id.

I understand that the params in my original example is id, and if I wanted the slug, I should rename my file to [slug].tsx and my params would be params.slug. Is it possible to utilize both the id and slug in my params and still have my query/route succeed?

I guess what I really want is to keep the relationship between my tables, but use the slug for querying the data (just for the url). I could make the FK the store slug, but I know it probably isnt the right move as the slug could change down the road.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is just a variable for whatever is in the route. If you want the route to be using the slug, you just need to change the filter to search for the slug `.eq('slug', params.id)`